# Cakephp3 CakePdf plugin not rendering pdf view

Tags: pdf, cakephp, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, cakephp-3.x

I'm trying to use CakePdf to render a pdf to view in the browser, but it doesn't seem to be being converted from html to pdf.
I followed the CakePdf instructions from https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf.

boostrap.php:

```
    Plugin::load('CakePdf', ['boostrap' => true]);
    Configure::write('CakePdf', [
    'engine' => 'CakePdf.WkHtmlToPdf',
    'margin' => [
        'bottom' => 20,
        'left' => 20,
        'right' => 20,
        'top' => 20
    ],
    'pageSize' => 'A4',
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'orientation' => 'portrait',
    'download' => false
]);
```

routes.php:

```
    Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json', 'xml', 'pdf']);
```

I have my layout in src/Template/Layout/pdf/default.ctp and have my view template in src/Template/Pos/pdf/printpo.ctp.  The requestHandler component is loaded in my AppController.

I can view localhost:8765/Pos/printpo/1 without a problem.  When I add the .pdf and am trying to view localhost:8765/Pos/printpo/1.pdf, Firefox says "this PDF document might not be displaying correctly".  When I download and try to open with document viewer, it says it can't open because file type plain/text is not supported.  If I open it with a text editor I can view the plain html, so it doesn't appear to converting the html at all.

I have CakePdf's 2nd use case working - I can save/write the pdf directly to the filesystem and it opens correctly.

Any help greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Have you loaded the `RequestHandler` component?

Comment: Yes.  It is being loaded in AppController

Comment: So the PDF file contain the plain HTML that is being generated in your pdf view templates? It's definitely not the code from the regular view templates? Any notices/warnings in the logs? Can you check what `debug(get_class($this))` outputs in your view template?

Comment: In any case I think you'll have to do some debugging, ie set some breakpoints in the plugin code to check at which point things are going wrong, the basic flow should be [**1**](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf/blob/3.1.1/src/View/PdfView.php#L117) > [**2**](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf/blob/3.1.1/src/Pdf/CakePdf.php#L271) > [**3**](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf/blob/3.1.1/src/Pdf/Engine/WkHtmlToPdfEngine.php#L36).

Comment: @ndm yeah the pdf file contains the plain HTML from my pdf view template, not the regular view template. Nothing in the logs...debug(get_class($this)) outputs App\View\AppView in both the pdfview template and the regular view template.  I'll try to step through the plugin code and see if I can find the guilty party

Comment: Having it output `App\View\AppView` means that the wrong view class is being used, it should use `CakePdf\View\PdfView`. The view [**is being registered**](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf/blob/3.1.1/config/bootstrap.php) on `Controller.initialize`, and requires the request handler component to be loaded _at that point_, make sure that you're not loading it at a later point.

Comment: It's being loaded in AppController.initialize - 'class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Authorize');
      ....  }  }'

Comment: @ndm could it possibly be an installation issue? Composer created the folders but didn't populate them w/ the correct files so when I first tried to use the plugin i had errors and ended up manually copying the src folder into project/vendor/friendsofcake/cakepdf.  I also for some reason have an project/plugins/cakepdf folder which was identical except the contents of the files were all blank. i copied project/vendor/friendsofcake/cakepdf to /plugins/cakepdf so those are identical now but still same result. thanks again for the help...sorry i'm a noob :D

Comment: Sounds pretty messy, for sure that could be the problems origin. Clean up your installation, remove all CakePDF bits (manually and [**via composer**](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#remove)), [**clear the composer cache**](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#clear-cache), and reinstall the plugin via composer.

Comment: @ndm ok, removed/reinstalled following your instructions. installation went smoothly this time. writing directly to server is working again but same issue w/ rendering.. debug(get_class($this)) still outputting App\View\AppView in both localhost/pos/view/1 and localhost/pos/view/1.pdf

Comment: It's debugging time then :)

Comment: @ndm that's what I was afraid of! haha i'll post what i come up with. may be a few days. thanks for your help :)

Comment: @ndm we decided to forgo debugging and just use a basic html template for display instead.i'm sure i screwed something simple up but on we go... thanks for the help :)